# Need help for understanding a sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

I am newbie started learning the linear algebra.
It might be dumb question.
But I don't understand how the sum of subspace can also be subspace?!

So for subset in order to be subspace,
It should satisfy 3 features:

1. Includes $0$
2. Closed under $+$
3. Closed under $\times$

I understand it.

But when it comes to sum of different two subspaces, the feature 2 above doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Suppose $U,W=\Bbb{R}^2$ (2 dimentions).
$$U=\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : y=0\}, \quad W=\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x=0\}.$$
Then $U+W=S$ is, in my intuitive thought going to be a cross only including all vectors along the origin lines($x$-axis and $y$-axis from $0$).
Then let's check if $S$ satisfies the addition feature.
$$(2,0) \in S, \quad (0,2) \in S,$$
then the addition vector of these two vector is not in $S$.

So it is quite confusing to me.
Maybe I'm taking a simple concept in the wrong way.
Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: YOu're doing a union, but the sum $U+W$ contains all vectors of the form $u+w$ where $u$ is in $U$ and $W$ is in $W$. So, for instance, since $(2,0)$ is in $W$ and $(0,2)$ is in $U$, then $(0,2)+(2,0) = (2,2)$ is in $U+W$, by definition.

Comment: What is your definition of "*sum of two different subspaces*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to notice that closure under addition might be missing if you only take the union of two subspaces. In general, the union of two subspaces is not a subspace. We can fix this by "filling in the gaps," which amounts to introducing all linear combinations of elements in both subspaces.

A good definition for this is to take the union of $U$ and $W$, and then take the span of the resulting union. Convince yourself that this fixes the problem!